# "Index out of range" Error with two Tableviews in one Viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview, return, tableview

I have two Tableviews in one ViewController. But if I run this my code I will get this error on line `let post = posts[indexPath.row]`:

> "Index out of range"

I think it has be something with the posts.count, but I can't figure it out. When I ran this code without the second Tableview `Tableview_moremaps` everything works just fine.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if comments.count == 0  {
                self.tableView.setEmptyMessage("No comments yet!")
            } else {
                self.tableView.restore()
            }

            if posts.count == 0 {
                self.Tableview_moremaps.setEmptyMessage("No other maps yet!")
            }else{
                self.Tableview_moremaps.restore()
            }

            if tableView == tableView {
                return comments.count
            }else{
                return posts.count
            }

        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            if tableView == self.tableView {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Comment", for: indexPath) as? CommentTableViewCell
                let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
                cell?.comment = comment
                cell?.delegate = self

                return cell!
            } else if tableView == Tableview_moremaps {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? MoremapsTableViewCell
                cell?.Map_image.image = nil
                let post = posts[indexPath.row]
                cell?.post = post
                cell?.delegate = self
                return cell!
            }

            return UITableViewCell()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `numberOfRowsInSection`, update the `if-condition`

```
   if tableView === self.tableView {
        return comments.count
    } else {
        return posts.count
    }
```

Currently `tableView == tableView` is always `true` and returned value is `comments` count.

Comment: If I use your code it will give me another error when I try to reload my tableview: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d477fd0)"

Comment: So, you have two problems. You have to fix that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the way you're using  `cellForRowAt`

Try giving each tableview an identifier with `tableView.accessibilityIdentifier = "myIdentifier"`
and then `cellForRowAt`would be like following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            if tableView.accessibilityIdentifier == "myIdentifier" {
                let cell = .....
                ...
...
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           if tableView == self.tableView {
        return comments.count

    }
    else{
        return posts.count
    }
}

//Your this code is perfect.(no issue here)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            if tableView == self.tableView {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Comment", for: indexPath) as? CommentTableViewCell
                let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
                cell?.comment = comment
                cell?.delegate = self

                return cell!
            } else if tableView == Tableview_moremaps {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? MoremapsTableViewCell
                cell?.Map_image.image = nil
                let post = posts[indexPath.row]
                cell?.post = post
                cell?.delegate = self
                return cell!
            }

            return UITableViewCell()
        }
```